# Creating an Extension To Edit Google Doc Spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension, google-apps-script

I'm brand new to coding extensions for chrome so I'm hoping someone here can help or point me in the right direction.

I'm looking to create an extension that when you click on it a drop down comes up with 2 text inputs that will allow me to edit a google doc spreadsheet on the fly. Specifically, I'm tracking customer issues for my site and need to continuously add the number of times per day an issue arises.

So in the first text input box I would like to enter #issue click "Track" and it would add a +1 to the corresponding issue's cell within the Google Doc. In the second text input box if I enter #issue2 *textdescription* and click "create new issue and track" then the function would create a new row describing the issue (*text description*) and create a rule that from now on when #issue2 is entered in the first "Track" input box then a +1 will be added to that corresponding cell.

I have been able to create a popup box with inputs, however I am having trouble figuring out how to create a function to carry out what I would like to have done to the Google Doc Spreadsheet.

Hopefully, this isn't too wordy :/

Answer (score 0):

Chrome extensions is not the way to go.
Look at google apps script. Use a menu,  sidebar or both.